# CEDET Semantic Analyzer rather slow on an otherwise fast system

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

My test setup:
Intel Dual Core 3GHz, Windows XP 32 bit, Emacs 23.2.1, CEDET v1.0 (byte-compiled as described in the INSTALL docs).

The Emacs init file only consists of these four lines:

```
(load "~/vendor/cedet/common/cedet.el")
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)
(require 'semantic-ia)
(global-ede-mode 1)
```

When opening a C++ file that includes just one function, completing that one function via (semantic-ia-complete-symbol) finishes only after a noticable lag, even after repeated tries.

Evaluating `semantic-analyze-current-context` shows that the sluggishness is caused by the Semantic analyzer.

Here's the [ELP result file](http://pastie.org/pastes/1529732/text) after running `semantic-elp-analyze` several times, without changing the point in the buffer. The total elapsed time is always about **0.6 seconds**.

When I add an include statement, like `#include <stdio.h>`, the timings change to **2.5 seconds**. Here's a corresponding [ELP result](http://pastie.org/pastes/1529741/text).

The same benchmarks never take longer than 0.1 seconds in my linux environment. (Same hardware, Debian's 23.1 Emacs, CEDET v1.0)

Any ideas what could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Have you byte-compiled cedet?

Comment: There were byte-compile errors. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that compiling CEDET threw a bunch of errors I didn't notice at first:

```
semantic-analyze.el:178:1:Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: filename
```

Which **caused the slowdown by leaving 81 files uncompiled.**

[Google suggests](http://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+%22Symbol%27s+value+as+variable+is+void%3a+filename%22) this error might be related to Emacs versions newer than 23.1.

If you use cedet-build.el for compiling CEDET, try the following workaround:

```
Add (setq filename nil) to the beginning of cedet-build.el
```

Comment: This is fixed in the development version of CEDET, which you can get by doing "bzr checkout bzr://cedet.bzr.sf.net/bzrroot/cedet/code/trunk"